# Calculate the total price of acquiring multiple cars - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my code:

```
double carsPrice = 0; 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of cars you would like to drive");
String [] numberOfCars = new String[sc.nextInt()];
while (numberOfCars.length > 5) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number that is less than 5 and try again");
    numberOfCars = new String[sc.nextInt()];
}
System.out.println("Enter the names of cars you would like to hire");
String [] chosenCarNames = new String[5];
sc.nextLine();
for (int i=0; i<numberOfCars.length; i++) {
    int nameA = i+1;
    System.out.println("Enter name of car " + nameA);
    chosenCarNames [i] = sc.nextLine();
    while ("lamborghini".equals(chosenCarNames[i]) && "toyota".equals(chosenCarNames[i]) && "audi 5".equals(chosenCarNames[i])) {
       if  (!"lamborghini".equals(chosenCarNames[i]) && !"toyota".equals(chosenCarNames[i]) && !"audi 5".equals(chosenCarNames[i])) {
           System.out.println("Name of car " + nameA + " is invalid. Please try again");
           chosenCarNames[i] = sc.nextLine();
       }
    } 
}
if ("lamborghini".equals(chosenCarNames[i])) {
    carsPrice = 59;
}
else if ("toyota".equals(chosenCarNames[i])) {
    carsPrice = 49;
}
else {
    carsPrice = 39;
}
```

I have made a java program that asks customers to enter the number of cars they would like to hire and after that the program should allow the user to enter the names of cars they would like to hire depending on the number of cars they would like to hire. My problem is that if the customer wants to hire more than one car, I am not able to calculate the total price the customer has to pay. If the customer wants to hire only one car, I have used if statements to calculate and display the total number of money the customer has to pay

Comment: Instead of assigning a number to `carsPrice`, you should add to that number.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the price calculation into the loop and accumulate it:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCars.length; i++) {
       int nameA = i+1;
       System.out.println("Enter name of car " + nameA);
       chosenCarNames [i] = sc.nextLine();

       // Input validation omitted for brevity
      
       if ("lamborghini".equals(chosenCarNames[i])) {
           carsPrice += 59;
       }
       else if ("toyota".equals(chosenCarNames[i])) {
           carsPrice += 49;
       }
       else {
           carsPrice += 39;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some interesting logic here:

```
while ("lamborghini".equals(chosenCarNames[i]) && "toyota".equals(chosenCarNames[i]) && "audi 5".equals(chosenCarNames[i])) {
```

If the entered value was "lamborghini", then the first part would be true, but then how could it also be equal to "toyota" and "audi" at the same time?

If the intention was to only allow "lamborghini", "toyota", or "audi 5", then move that compound boolean expression from the inner `if` statement out to the `while` loop, and get rid of the inner `if`:

```
System.out.println("Enter name of car " + nameA);
chosenCarNames [i] = sc.nextLine();
while (!"lamborghini".equals(chosenCarNames[i]) && !"toyota".equals(chosenCarNames[i]) && !"audi 5".equals(chosenCarNames[i])) {
   System.out.println("Name of car " + nameA + " is invalid. Please try again");
   chosenCarNames[i] = sc.nextLine();
}
```